Crypto Currency App in Android Studio using Kotlin
I am trying to create a simple app that will display cryptocurrencies. The app runs in Android studio, but it appears my issues is the spinner. It does not show the crypto from the API. Any thoughts?
import android.content.Context

data class CryptoInfo(
    val name: String,
    val symbol: String,
    val supply: Int,
    val priceUSD: Double,
    val percentChange24h: Double
)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val cryptoList = ArrayList<CryptoInfo>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        fetchDataFromAPI()

    }


    private fun fetchDataFromAPI() {
        Log.d("MyTag", "Fetching data from API...")
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets"

        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data")
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val cryptoObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val name = cryptoObject.getString("name")
                    val symbol = cryptoObject.getString("symbol")
                    val supply = cryptoObject.get3Double("supply").toInt()
                    val priceUSD = cryptoObject.getDouble("priceUsd")
                    val percentChange24h = cryptoObject.getDouble("changePercent24Hr")

                    cryptoList.add(CryptoInfo(name, symbol, supply, priceUSD, percentChange24h))
                }

                // Populate spinner with cryptocurrency names
                val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
                val cryptoNames = cryptoList.map { it.name }
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cryptoNames)
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                spinner.adapter = adapter

                // Handle spinner item selection
                spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                        updateCryptoInfo(cryptoList[position])
                    }

                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("API_ERROR", "Error fetching data: ${error.message}")
            })

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }

    private fun updateCryptoInfo(cryptoInfo: CryptoInfo) {
        // Update TextViews with cryptocurrency information
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cryptoNameTextView).text = cryptoInfo.name
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.symbolTextView).text = cryptoInfo.symbol
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.supplyTextView).text = cryptoInfo.supply.toString()
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.priceTextView).text = String.format("%.2f", cryptoInfo.priceUSD)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.percentChangeTextView).text = String.format("%.2f%%", cryptoInfo.percentChange24h)
    }
}

I went back and made sure my reference IDs were correct and included  in my android manifest. When clicking on the dropdown, it is meant to show different cryptocurrencies for you to choose from.

when you do updateCryptoInfo(cryptoList[position]) you update the spinner info with CryptoInfo objects
that fuction run once when you create the spinners

Welcome on StackOverflow. It's difficult to understand your answer. I suggest you to check [answer], format it then add details to explain why and how it should fix the issue
